# ¿Android Studio elimina los recursos que no usa la app o los deja aunque no se usen?

Tags: android, android-studio

Tengo una duda: si tengo en mi proyecto en Android Studio recursos que la aplicación como tal no utiliza (por ejemplo, unas fotos que no se utilicen en la app) pero estas están guardadas en la carpeta /drawable, cuando compilo la apk, ¿Android studio elimina esas fotos o simplemente las deja en la apk compilada ocupando espacio aunque no se usen?

Comment: No tienes que buscar en tu proyecto cuales recursos no se estan usando, si deseas removerlos simplemente realiza Refactor > Remove Unused resources.

Answer (score 1):

Depende de como tú lo tengas definido en el Gradle, para ser más exactos de las propiedades minifyEnabled y shrinkResources. [Documentación.](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html?hl=es-419)

> ¿Qué significa exactamente "minifyEnabled" y "shrinkResources" ?

minifycorre encoge sólo código y shrinkeliminar elimina recursos marcado como no utilizados de la carpeta res. ProGuard es el que realmente analiza el código para saber lo que no se utiliza.

Ojo.. shrinkResourcesse se tiene en cuenta sólo si minifyEnabledes es verdadadero

> ¿Alguna de estas opciones afectan el tamaño y / o la calidad de los archivos de imagen?

¡No!

Answer (score 0):

Eso depende de la configuración en tu `build.gradle`

Así se elimina lo que no se necesita:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
```

y así no:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        minifyEnabled false
```

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Android Studio elimina los recursos que no usa la app o los deja
>   aunque no se usen?

La respuesta es no los elimina, por default los recursos permanecen en el .apk generado.

para eliminar los recursos fácilmente ve al menú opción:

> **Refactor** > **Remove Unused resources**

con esta opción los recursos que no son usados en tu proyecto serán removidos con facilidad y no tendrás que estar buscando en el proyecto.

---

Las propiedades `shrinkResources` y `minifyEnabled`  en realidad no eliminan los recursos no usados por la aplicación.

> `shrinkResources` fusiona recursos con nombres similares que en
>   ocasiones podemos dejar en directorios de recursos diferentes.
>
> `minifyEnabled` para la reducción y optimización de código.

esto se puede configurar dentro del archivo: build.gradle

```
android {
    ...
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
                    'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```